# How to validate Aadhaar XML signature in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-signature, aadhaar

I'm trying to do XML signature validation.
Here is the link to Aadhaar Paperless Offline e-kyc tutorial https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/about-aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc.html

```
with open('/home/user/Downloads/uidai_auth_sign_prod_2023.cer', 'rb') as f:
     key = f.read()
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse("/home/user/Downloads/offlineaadhaar202205040207.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
try:
    verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(root, require_x509=False, x509_cert=key).signed_xml
    print("Data is : %s" % verified_data)
except Exception as exce:
    print(exce)
```

This code is giving error:

> Signature verification failed: invalid padding

If there is any other solution to verify xml signature. please let us know.

Comment: I am trying to validate xml signature. but above code results signature verificationfailed: invalid padding error

Comment: in your case, u need to use different certificate from here https://uidai.gov.in/images/authDoc/uidai_auth_sign_prod.cer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out XMLVerifier usefull to verify signed xml.
**pip package need to be install**

> pip install signxml

here is my working snippet

**Code**

```
from signxml import XMLVerifier
aadhar_file = '<path_to_signed_aadhaar_xml>'
cert = open('path_to_uidai_auth_sign_prod_2023.pem', "r+").read()
root = le.parse(aadhar_file).getroot()
try:
    verify = XMLVerifier().verify(root, x509_cert=cert)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

In case of invalid signature this will throw an exception

> InvalidDigest: Digest mismatch for reference 0

NOTE: ***Kindly use valid certificate(Based on recommended by https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/about-aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc.html) to validate aadhaar xml***

Comment: Its throwing error, `Signature method RSA_SHA1 forbidden by configuration`.

Comment: in downloaded e-KYC xml `<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>` and signxml forbids it.

Comment: @ArunKumarKhattri, +1 .  Is there any workaround?

Comment: @dhananjay_shingote signxml 3.1 version allows `rsa-sha1`

Comment: Thanks @ArunKumarKhattri for reply. Somehow, I am getting same error. Are there any code changes required?

Comment: my apologies @dhananjay_shingote signxml version is 3.0.1, try this.